# Type casting of Macro to optimize the code

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Working on to optimize the code. Is it good idea to type cast the macro to `char` to reduce the memory consumption? What could be the side effect of doing this?

Example:

```
#define TRUE 1 //non-optimized code 
sizeof(TRUE) --> 4

#define TRUE 1 ((char) 0x01) //To optimize 
sizeof(TRUE) --> 1

#define MAX 10 //non-optimized code 
sizeof(MAX) --> 4

#define MAX ((char) 10) //To optimize 
sizeof(MAX) --> 1
```

Comment: That is at best sub-micro-optimization. It could be a pessimization.

Comment: The best idea would be to erase this code and use `stdbool.h`

Comment: Macros don't have any memory consumption.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to code up both versions and compare the generated binaries.  You will likely see no difference in the memory footprint.

Comment: @JohnBode Actually, we have had a similar argument at where I am working. We use a 32-bit ARM, and the other guy argued it is better to work with explicit `uint32_t` for the boolean stuff. I claimed it is better to use `bool` where logically correct. And the otherwise identical code generated less instructions with `bool`. (actually, while thinking of it now it could be because `bool` should be compared to `int` rather than `uint32_t`)

Comment: What in case of MAX as value 10?

Comment: *What could be the side effect of doing this?* - Waste of a lot of time without any benefit

Comment: ...and with a potential harm. Like what if someone decides to change `MAX` to something like `1236` without thinking much?

Comment: A typical PC might have 8,000,000,000 bytes of RAM. How good is it to save 3 of those when storing a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will make virtually no difference in memory consumption.

These macros provide values to be used in expressions, while the actual memory usage is (roughly) dictated by the type and number of variables and dynamically allocated memory. So, you may have `TRUE` as an `int` or as a `char`, but what actually matters is the type of variable it (or, the expression in which it appears) gets assigned to, which is not influenced by the type of the constant.

The only influence the type of these constants may have is in how the expressions they are used into are carried out - but even that effect should be almost non existant, given that the C standard (simplifying) implicitly promotes to `int` or `unsigned` all the smaller types before carrying out almost any operation.<sup>1</sup>

---

So: if you want to reduce your memory consumption, don't look at your constants, but at your data structures, possibly global and dynamically-allocates ones<sup>2</sup>! Maybe you have a huge array of `double` values where the precision of `float` would be enough, maybe you are keeping around big data longer than you need it, or you have memory leaks, or a big array of a badly-laid-out `struct`, or of booleans that are 4-byte wide when they could be a bitfield - this is the kind of thing you should look after, definitely not these `#define`s.

---

#### Notes

1. The idea being that integral operations are carried out at the native register size, which traditionally corresponds to `int`. Besides, even if this rule wasn't true, the only memory effect of changing the size of integral temporary values in expressions may be at most to increase a bit the stack usage (which is generally mostly preallocated anyway) in case of heavy register spilling.
2. What is allocated on the stack generally isn't problematic - as said above, it's generally preallocated, and if you were exhausting it your program would be already crashing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a `char` constant in C, which is why there are no suffixes for "short" and "char", as there are for "long" and "long long". The casted value of `(char)0x10` will immediately be promoted back to an `int` in almost any integer context, because of the integer promotions (§6.3.1.1p2).

So if `c` is a `char` and you write `if (c == (char)0x10) ...`, 
*both* `x` and `(char)0x10` are promoted to `int` before being compared.

Of course, a given compiler might  elide the conversion if it knows that it makes no difference, but that compiler would certainly also use a byte constant if possible even without the explicit cast.

Answer (score -1):

The optimization level depends on (1) where those defines are used and (2) what is the processor's arquitecture (or microcontroller) you're running the code.

The (1) has already been addressed in other answers.

The (2) is importante because there are processors/microcontrollers that perform better with 8 bits instead of 32 bits. There are processors that are, for example, 16 bits and if you use 8 bits variables it could decrease the memory needed but increase the run time of the program.

Below are an example and its disassemble:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define _VAR_UINT8      ((uint8_t)  -1)
#define _VAR_UINT16     ((uint16_t) -1)
#define _VAR_UINT32     ((uint32_t) -1)
#define _VAR_UINT64     ((uint64_t) -1)

volatile uint8_t v1b;
volatile uint16_t v2b;
volatile uint32_t v4b;
volatile uint64_t v8b;

int main(void) {

   v1b = _VAR_UINT8;

   v2b = _VAR_UINT8;
   v2b = _VAR_UINT16;

   v4b = _VAR_UINT8;
   v4b = _VAR_UINT16;
   v4b = _VAR_UINT32;

   v8b = _VAR_UINT8;
   v8b = _VAR_UINT16;
   v8b = _VAR_UINT32;
   v8b = _VAR_UINT64;

   return 0;
}
```

Below are the disassemble for a x86 32 bit specific platform (it could be differente if you compile the above code and generate the disassemble in our processor)

```
00000000004004ec <main>:
  4004ec:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ed:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f0:   c6 05 49 0b 20 00 ff    movb   $0xff,0x200b49(%rip)        # 601040 <v1b>
  4004f7:   66 c7 05 48 0b 20 00    movw   $0xff,0x200b48(%rip)        # 601048 <v2b>
  4004fe:   ff 00 
  400500:   66 c7 05 3f 0b 20 00    movw   $0xffff,0x200b3f(%rip)        # 601048 <v2b>
  400507:   ff ff 
  400509:   c7 05 31 0b 20 00 ff    movl   $0xff,0x200b31(%rip)        # 601044 <v4b>
  400510:   00 00 00 
  400513:   c7 05 27 0b 20 00 ff    movl   $0xffff,0x200b27(%rip)        # 601044 <v4b>
  40051a:   ff 00 00 
  40051d:   c7 05 1d 0b 20 00 ff    movl   $0xffffffff,0x200b1d(%rip)        # 601044 <v4b>
  400524:   ff ff ff 
  400527:   48 c7 05 06 0b 20 00    movq   $0xff,0x200b06(%rip)        # 601038 <v8b>
  40052e:   ff 00 00 00 
  400532:   48 c7 05 fb 0a 20 00    movq   $0xffff,0x200afb(%rip)        # 601038 <v8b>
  400539:   ff ff 00 00 
  40053d:   c7 05 f1 0a 20 00 ff    movl   $0xffffffff,0x200af1(%rip)        # 601038 <v8b>
  400544:   ff ff ff 
  400547:   c7 05 eb 0a 20 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x200aeb(%rip)        # 60103c <v8b+0x4>
  40054e:   00 00 00 
  400551:   48 c7 05 dc 0a 20 00    movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,0x200adc(%rip)        # 601038 <v8b>
  400558:   ff ff ff ff 
  40055c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400561:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400562:   c3                      retq   
  400563:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40056a:   00 00 00 
  40056d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

In my specific platform it is using 4 types of `mov` instruction, `movb` (7 bytes), `movw` (9 bytes), `movl` (10 bytes) and `movq` (12 bytes) depending upon the variable type and also the data type to be assigned.

Comment: "Below are the disassemble for a x86 32 bit specific platform" nope, that is 64 bit code. 32 bit x86 doesn't have rip addressing, nor 64 bit registers (rsp, rbp, rax). Also, as already explained, your point (2) is not relevant if we are comparing `int` with smaller types, because in almost all operations `short` and `char` values are implicitly promoted to `int` before performing any calculation on them, so the type of constants is generally irrelevant; remove all those casts from your code and you'll see little to no difference. The differing `mov`s come from the type of the target variables.

Comment: (incidentally, identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation in all scopes; don't use them)

Comment: Actually, there *is* a difference here between having and not having those casts, and comes from the fact that `(uint8_t)-1` and `(uint16_t)-1` are different numbers (255 and 65535), so assigning them to a wider type results in logically different behavior (so it's not an optimization, it's actually a different operation).